# Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, math

If I execute the following expression in C#:

```
double i = 10*0.69;
```

`i` is: `6.8999999999999995`. Why?

I understand numbers such as 1/3 can be hard to represent in binary as it has infinite recurring decimal places but this is not the case for 0.69. And 0.69 can easily be represented in binary, one binary number for 69 and another to denote the position of the decimal place.

How do I work around this? Use the `decimal` type?

Comment: Please consider this: What are the chances that you stumbled upon a bug like this in a framework that has been around for years?

Comment: You'll get a similar result in almost any other language/framework that correctly implements floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Heh heh. It's a immutable truth; anytime you read a topic with '... multiplication broken in abc language ... ' it will be about floating point :)

Comment: Well it was slightly tongue in cheek. None the less its an interesting problem.

Comment: Brian: I don't think that's a good approach. I think you can reasonably assume there may be a problem, but I also think it is reasonable to research into it yourself. Back in the day I remember finding Java bugs; it doesn't mean I'm special, it's just an accident. Research is what needs to be taught.

Comment: Bugs in the .NET framework? Don't be ridiculous: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867460 Although one with floating point arithmetic would be a big one

Comment: Link above should be http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945757

Comment: "If you think you've found a bug in {compiler,operating system,framework}, You're Wrong."

Comment: 0.69 is not exactly representable in binary: It's expansion is something like 1/2+1/8+1/16+1/512+1/2048+1/32768+...

Comment: i like how the explanation of how to store it in BINARY relies on specifying where the DECIMAL place is

Comment: Dear question maker, I think your expectation is right. 10 * 0.69 is 6.9
Computer scientists made mistake, and ruins the world, brings suffer and pain with this.

Comment: @jk. theoretically it can be generalized to the [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point), though

Comment: The answer to the original question is YES. IEEE754 64-bit binary floating point, which virtually all CPUs implement, is broken for decimal arithmetic. That's why .NET also offers the `decimal` type.

Comment: With a minor change, the results are different: 10*0.69m == 6.90. So using decimal instead of double gives the correct result.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Because you've misunderstood floating point arithmetic and how data is stored.

In fact, your code isn't actually performing any arithmetic at execution time in this particular case - the *compiler* will have done it, then saved a constant in the generated executable. However, it *can't* store an exact value of 6.9, because that value cannot be precisely represented in floating point point format, just like 1/3 can't be precisely stored in a finite decimal representation.

See if [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) helps you.

Comment: I might be showing my naivety, but why doesn't the framework work around this and hide this problem from me and give me the right answer,0.69!!!

Comment: @Dan: Because you might not *mean* 0.69. You might mean any of the other many values which would be represented by the same bit pattern. If you want to represent values which are fundamentally decimal in nature, you should use the `decimal` type to start with. Note that choosing the "output" here is a matter of working out how to convert an instance of a particular type into a *text* format... that's somewhat separate from deciding which type to use in the first place.

Comment: Dan: because "double" is computerese for "I'd rather have it done fast than done right."

Comment: @Jon: Maybee you should consider adding your name to the article. It gets additional credibility that way. And maybe also add an date that it was written (in case binary floating point implementation changes in future :)).

Comment: I could possibly add my name at the bottom of all my articles. Will consider it. As for dating it - I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @RobertL, I realize I am "way late to this party" but your comment is my absolute favorite!

Comment: @RobertL I realize it was tongue in cheek, but... double is just as fine as decimal for certain kinds of calculations. It's just that it will not tend to match with the calculations you do in decimal with pen & paper :D

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @Estevez: To what specific task? I've explained why the result is what it is, but in order to have a "solution" there'd have to be a particular goal. In many cases the answer is "don't use `double` if you care about precise decimal representations".

Comment: 6.9 in binary is `110.11100110011001100...` and in IEEE 754 32-bit single precision: `0-10000001-10111001100110011001100`

Answer (score 53):

> why doesn't the framework work around this and hide this problem from me and give me the 
>   right answer,0.69!!!

Stop behaving like a dilbert manager, and accept that computers, though cool and awesome, have limits.  In your specific case, it doesn't just "hide" the problem, because you have specifically told it not to.  The language (the computer) provides alternatives to the format, that you didn't choose.  You chose double, which has certain advantages over decimal, and certain downsides.  Now, knowing the answer, you're upset that the downsides don't magically disappear.

As a programmer, you are responsible for hiding this downside from managers, and there are many ways to do that.  However, the makers of C# have a responsibility to make floating point work correctly, and correct floating point will occasionally result in incorrect math.

So will every other number storage method, as we do not have infinite bits.  Our job as programmers is to work with limited resources to make cool things happen.  They got you 90% of the way there, just get the torch home.

Comment: Well admittedly I don't have a deep understanding of this. But I was thinking there must be some sort of work around to this, such as using some alternate notation, it seems to be the number 69 its easily storable in binary, as well as the position of a decimal point.

Comment: @Dan: and that, essentially (I believe), is what a Decimal does. So yes, you should have used that if you wanted an exact answer.

Comment: (much confusion over Dan's)  -  Yes Decimal does solve that particular problem.  It adds some of it's own.  Without knowing the details of the problem, it's hard to say which is "Correct" for you.  It may very well be that the "correct" solution to your problem is to store a Double and round it off for your users.

Comment: @Dan: The decimal place is stored in binary. So it comes after a position like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, etc.

Comment: Read http://binary-system.base-conversion.ro/convert-real-numbers-from-decimal-system-to-32bit-single-precision-IEEE754-binary-floating-point.php to see why a computer shows you that!

Answer (score 16):

> And 0.69 can easily be represented in
>   binary, one binary number for 69 and
>   another to denote the position of the
>   *decimal* place.

I think this is a common mistake - you're thinking of floating point numbers as if they are base-10 (i.e decimal - hence my emphasis).

So - you're thinking that there are two whole-number parts to this double: **69** and **divide by 100** to get the decimal place to move - which could also be expressed as:
**69 x 10 to the power of -2**.

However floats store the 'position of the point' as *base-2*.

Your float actually gets stored as:
    **68999999999999995 x 2 to the power of some big negative number**

This isn't as much of a problem once you're used to it - most people know and expect that 1/3 can't be expressed accurately as a decimal or percentage. It's just that the fractions that can't be expressed in base-2 are different.

Comment: We might just need to say "recurring binary places" and "move the binary point" to get the idea across.

Comment: "68999999999999995 x 2 to the power of some big negative number" is not true. The mantissa does not look like 690(...)0; it's something different entirely.

Comment: @NayukiMinase yeah, I know, I've just tried to simplify it for the explanation. The real mantissa will look like an unrelated number and be in binary. This is concept people get in decimal (for instance 1/3 being 0.333...) but don't realise applies to different numbers in binary (for instance 1.1)

Answer (score 12):

> but why doesn't the framework work around this and hide this problem from me and give me the right answer,0.69!!!

Because you told it to use *binary floating point*, and the solution is to use *decimal floating point*, so you are suggesting that the framework should disregard the type you specified and use *decimal* instead, which is very much slower because it is not directly implemented in hardware.

A more efficient solution is to not output the full value of the representation and explicitly specify the accuracy required by your output. If you format the output to two decimal places, you will see the result you expect. However if this is a financial application *decimal* is precisely what you should use - you've seen Superman III (and Office Space) haven't you ;)

Note that it is all a finite approximation of an infinite range, it is merely that *decimal* and *double* use a different set of approximations. The advantage of *decimal* is it produces the same approximations that you would if you were performing the calculation yourself. For example if you calculated 1/3, you would eventually stop writing 3's when it was 'good enough'.

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason that 1 / 3 in a decimal systems comes out as 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 and not the exact fraction, which is infinitely long.

Comment: Read http://binary-system.base-conversion.ro/convert-real-numbers-from-decimal-system-to-32bit-single-precision-IEEE754-binary-floating-point.php to learn how computers round it!

Answer (score 7):

To work around it (e.g. to display on screen) try this:

```
double i = (double) Decimal.Multiply(10, (Decimal) 0.69);
```

Everyone seems to have answered your first question, but ignored the second part.

Comment: Idk why this is not the accepted answer.