# Formatting doubles for output in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, floating-point, ieee-754

Running a quick experiment related to [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net) and reading a couple of articles on C# string formatting, I thought that this:

```
{
    double i = 10 * 0.69;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", i));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("+ {0:F20}", 6.9 - i));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("= {0:F20}", 6.9));
}
```

Would be the C# equivalent of this C code:

```
{
    double i = 10 * 0.69;

    printf ( "%f\n", i );
    printf ( "  %.20f\n", i );
    printf ( "+ %.20f\n", 6.9 - i );
    printf ( "= %.20f\n", 6.9 );
}
```

However the C# produces the output:

```
6.9
  6.90000000000000000000
+ 0.00000000000000088818
= 6.90000000000000000000
```

*despite i showing up equal to the value 6.89999999999999946709 (rather than 6.9) in the debugger.*

compared with C which shows the precision requested by the format:

```
6.900000                          
  6.89999999999999946709          
+ 0.00000000000000088818          
= 6.90000000000000035527
```

What's going on?

( Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.51 SP1 / Visual Studio C# 2008 Express Edition )

---

I have a background in numerical computing and experience implementing interval arithmetic - a technique for estimating errors due to the limits of precision in complicated numerical systems - on various platforms. To get the bounty, don't try and explain about the storage precision - in this case it's a difference of one ULP of a 64 bit double.

To get the bounty, I want to know how (or whether) .Net can format a double to the requested precision as visible in the C code.

Comment: Looks to me like C# is showing the same precision, just that it deals with numbers alot more precisely than C++ does...

Comment: It's also entirely possible the C# compiler looks at 10* 0.69 and says to itself "oooh, I know this one, it's 6.9!" and sustitutes that in inplace of actually doing the calculation at runtime.

Comment: FWIW - using 'i' for a double variable is giving me cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Double arithmetic uses floating-point maths, so this is to be expected, and why I refuse to use doubles when dealing with financial data. I use decimal in C# and money or numeric(18,7) in SQL depending on requirements.

Comment: @Randoplh Potter: The poster's complaint is that .NET's String.Format isn't showing the double approximation when pulled out to 20 decimal places.

Comment: Is there a difference if you turn off optimizations?

Comment: @Randolph: I've found that if you're working with money, the easiest way is to work with integer values that represent the number of cents rather than the number of dollars (or whatever accuracy is needed for the application).

Comment: @"just that it deals with numbers alot more precisely " if i was 6.9 to the precision it was working to, 6.9 - i would be zero.

Comment: @Paul Williams - no difference; values are the same as C in debugger but still output rounded to less that 20 dp.

Comment: "despite i showing up equal to the value 6.89999999999999946709 (rather than 6.9) in the debugger" - Are you sure ? I get a 6.8999999999999995 in my VS2008

Comment: @Matthew you are probably right about this. You can use Reflector to check for sure.  Making separate variables would avoid this:
double ten = 10; //dont use const keyword
double i = ten * 0.69;

Comment: @Matthew, yeah you're right, but why is that making such things? btw, you can get this by simply `Console.WriteLine(6.9 - 10 * 0.69);`

Comment: @Matthew: yes, the C# spec states that it should calculate any literal at compile if possible. But the resulting value, `6.9`, will still be stored as IEEE-754 floating point double. The value you see is not because "the CLI knows this one", but because it's a valid (ie.e, within range) and readable interpretation of the floating point value.

Comment: Note that .Net Core 6 returns the same as C for `F20`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The problem is that .NET will always round a `double` to 15 significant decimal digits *before* applying your formatting, regardless of the precision requested by your format and regardless of the exact decimal value of the binary number.

I'd guess that the Visual Studio debugger has its own format/display routines that directly access the internal binary number, hence the discrepancies between your C# code, your C code and the debugger.

There's nothing built-in that will allow you to access the exact decimal value of a `double`, or to enable you to format a `double` to a specific number of decimal places, but you could do this yourself by picking apart the internal binary number and rebuilding it as a string representation of the decimal value.

Alternatively, you could use Jon Skeet's [`DoubleConverter` class](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) (linked to from his ["Binary floating point and .NET" article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)). This has a `ToExactString` method which returns the exact decimal value of a `double`. You could easily modify this to enable rounding of the output to a specific precision.

```
double i = 10 * 0.69;
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(i));
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(6.9 - i));
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(6.9));

// 6.89999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625
// 0.00000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
// 6.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
```

Comment: The correct out for case 1 is 6.8999999999999995, both .NET and Jon Skeet get this wrong. The trailing digits are garbage digits.

Comment: No, these are not garbage digits, these are the decimal representation of the closest approximation of the binary representation of a decimal number. This is not arbitrary, just pure math based on the IEEE-754 specification and the 52 bits fraction. The number you mention is a rounded number. For instance, the middle number is equal to `1/2^50`, in other words, it's one bit off.

Comment: They're garbage in the sense that they can be thrown away without losing anything of the value - a double value represents an interval on the real number line, not an exact value, so 6.8999999999999995 is as much a correct value as the 'exact' version, as both fall in the interval. There are three different behaviours which are all correct in some way- the decimal value with the smallest number of digits which is within the interval (the roundtrip value or leppie's scheme value), the centre of the interval (the 'exact' value above) or a range half a ULP either side of the exact value.

Comment: Do you have a reference for ".NET will always round a double to 15 significant decimal digits before applying your formatting"?

Comment: @Pete: All the documentation seems to *suggest* that this is the case, but admittedly I can't find anything definitive. The closest I've found is probably in the "remarks" section of the `ToString` documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

Comment: By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. If the value of this instance has greater than 15 digits, `ToString` returns `PositiveInfinitySymbol` or `NegativeInfinitySymbol` instead of the expected number. If you require more precision, specify *format* with the "G17" format specification, which always returns 17 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 15 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision.

Comment: On *"All the documentation seems to suggest that this is the case"*  (Luke) and *"reference for '.NET will always round a double to 15..'"* >> see the SSCLI or my answer further in this thread: it is actually *very deliberate*.

Comment: On *"although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally"* >> yes and no: internally, the IEEE-754 `double` is maintained, which is almost the same, but technically rather different. But considering the level of this discussion, I'm under the impression that everybody already knows these differences.

Comment: @Luke: "R" can sometimes return up to 19 digits. But in most cases, it will add 1 garbage digit.

Comment: @Abel, @leppie: The text that I posted in the big comment isn't mine, it's just a quote taken from the MSDN docs for `Double.ToString`. Whether that documentation is accurate or not is another matter!

Comment: @Luke: I was fooled then by it too  :)

Comment: @PeteKirkham That is usually true, but occasionally it's important to know the exact value of a double. I work on simulations, and I often log the value of a double input to a method. I expect that if I pass that same double to the same method in a later simulation run, the method will give exactly the same result.

Here's a famous example of where tiny rounding errors affected a simulation: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsbm.2009.0004 (page 143, last two paragraphs).

Comment: @hypehuman you misunderstood. The binary representation of the double is exactly the same whether the 'garbage' digits are there or not in the decimal representation, so there is no mechanism whereby they can affect a calculation - the difference is less than one unit in the last place, so the value is exactly the same when round tripped. I suspect Lorenz' output was truncated.

Answer (score 28):

```
Digits after decimal point
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"

// max. two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
// at least two digits before decimal point
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 123.4567);      // "123.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 23.4567);       // "23.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 3.4567);        // "03.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", -3.4567);       // "-03.5"

Thousands separator
String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);     // "12,345.7"
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);       // "12,346"

Zero
Following code shows how can be formatted a zero (of double type).

String.Format("{0:0.0}", 0.0);            // "0.0"
String.Format("{0:0.#}", 0.0);            // "0"
String.Format("{0:#.0}", 0.0);            // ".0"
String.Format("{0:#.#}", 0.0);            // ""

Align numbers with spaces
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", 123.4567);    // "     123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", 123.4567);   // "123.5     "
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", -123.4567);   // "    -123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", -123.4567);  // "-123.5    "

Custom formatting for negative numbers and zero
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 123.4567);   // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", -123.4567);  // "minus 123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 0.0);        // "zero"

Some funny examples
String.Format("{0:my number is 0.0}", 12.3);   // "my number is 12.3"
String.Format("{0:0aaa.bbb0}", 12.3);
```

Comment: I can find http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ by myself; the question was about the behaviour when the value with the number of digits requested did not agree with the precision in the variable.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). In the notes it states that the numbers are rounded to the number of decimal places requested.

If instead you use "{0:R}" it will produce what's referred to as a "round-trip" value, take a look at this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString) for more info, here's my code and the output:

```
double d = 10 * 0.69;
Console.WriteLine("  {0:R}", d);
Console.WriteLine("+ {0:F20}", 6.9 - d);
Console.WriteLine("= {0:F20}", 6.9);
```

*output*

```
  6.8999999999999995
+ 0.00000000000000088818
= 6.90000000000000000000
```

Comment: I don't want the round trip value, I want to know how to get the value rounded to the number of decimal places I ask for, which in this case would be 6.89999999999999946709.

Comment: If I recall correctly the double data type is accurate to 16 digits, so the number in my sample is the most accurate you'll get, any more digits than that would require a larger data type.

Comment: Here's a quote from the MSDN documentation:  By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally

Comment: I wouldn't mind if FF20 printed out 6.89999999999999950000, as there aren't any intermediate values between d and 6.9, but it doesn't - it prints out a value which is neither the requested precision, nor is the precision that is used internally, nor is the round trip value. Very odd.

Comment: Yes, I found that odd too, I tried a few ways to get the extra 0's on the end, nothing worked... I guess I could do an old hack of padding but it feels ugly (e.g. pad n x 0 where n = requestedLength - d.ToString("R").Length ).

Answer (score 8):

Though this question is meanwhile closed, I believe it is worth mentioning how this atrocity came into existence. In a way, you may blame the C# spec, which states that a double must have a precision of 15 or 16 digits (the result of IEEE-754). A bit further on (section 4.1.6) it's stated that implementations are allowed to use *higher* precision. Mind you: *higher*, not lower. They are even allowed to deviate from IEEE-754: expressions of the type `x * y / z` where `x * y` would yield `+/-INF` but would be in a valid range after dividing, do not have to result in an error. This feature makes it easier for compilers to use higher precision in architectures where that'd yield better performance.

But I promised a "reason". Here's a quote (you requested a resource in one of your recent comments) from the [Shared Source CLI](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en), in `clr/src/vm/comnumber.cpp`:

> *"In order to give numbers that are both
>   friendly to display and
>   round-trippable, we parse the number
>   using 15 digits and then determine if
>   it round trips to the same value.  If
>   it does, we convert that NUMBER to a
>   string, otherwise we reparse using 17
>   digits and display that."*

In other words: MS's CLI Development Team decided to be both round-trippable and show pretty values that aren't such a pain to read. Good or bad? I'd wish for an opt-in or opt-out.

The trick it does to find out this round-trippability of any given number? Conversion to a generic NUMBER structure (which has separate fields for the properties of a double) and back, and then compare whether the result is different. If it is different, the exact value is used (as in your middle value with `6.9 - i`) if it is the same, the "pretty value" is used.

As you already remarked in a comment to Andyp, `6.90...00` is bitwise equal to `6.89...9467`. And now you know why `0.0...8818` is used: it is bitwise different from `0.0`.

This *15 digits barrier* is hard-coded and can only be changed by recompiling the CLI, by using Mono or by calling Microsoft and convincing them to add an option to print full "precision" (it is not really precision, but by the lack of a better word). It's probably easier to just calculate the 52 bits precision yourself or use the library mentioned earlier.

EDIT: if you like to experiment yourself with IEE-754 floating points, [consider this online tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/64bit.html), which shows you all relevant parts of a floating point.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:G17}", i));
```

That will give you all the 17 digits it have. By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. {0:R} will not always give you 17 digits, it will give 15 if the number can be represented with that precision.

which returns 15 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision. There isn't any thing you can to do to make the the double return more digits that is the way it's implemented. If you don't like it do a new double class yourself...

.NET's double cant store any more digits than 17 so you cant see 6.89999999999999946709 in the debugger you would see 6.8999999999999995. Please provide an image to prove us wrong.

Comment: double doesn't store 17 decimal digits - it stores 52+1 binary digits.  The exact representation of 1/2^52 is 52 decimal digits long, so it should be able to output 52 decimal digits before having trailing zeros. I'm trying to get around truncation to a decimal value. The value in the debugger is as I describe - the same as is output in C.

Comment: what I meant was "17 digits of precision"

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is simple and can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)

> Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal number, and that the precision of a floating-point number determines how accurately that number approximates a decimal number. By default, a Double value contains **15 decimal digits of precision**, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

In your example, the value of i is 6.89999999999999946709  which has the number 9 for all positions between the 3rd and the 16th digit (remember to count the integer part in the digits). When converting to string, the framework rounds the number to the 15th digit.

```
i     = 6.89999999999999 946709
digit =           111111 111122
        1 23456789012345 678901
```

Comment: All this is roughly true, though glosses over how IEE double works in x87 and SSE systems which are relevant to the sort of work I do - particularly if you can implement interval arithmetic on .net, where making the ULP visible matters. The question is how to format the output to get the internal value to user specified number of places, not the rounded value which truncates it.

Answer (score 2):

i tried to reproduce your findings, but when I watched 'i' in the debugger it showed up as '6.8999999999999995' not as '6.89999999999999946709' as you wrote in the question. Can you provide steps to reproduce what you saw?

To see what the debugger shows you, you can use a DoubleConverter as in the following line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(i).ConvertTo(i, typeof(string)));
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: I guess I'm more tired than I thought, of course this is the same as formatting to the roundtrip value (as mentioned before).

Comment: The value shows up in the debugger as equal to the value rendered by C formatting as "6.89999999999999946709", rather than "6.90..0" which is output by .Net's string formatting.  6.8999999999999995 is bitwise equal to 6.89999999999999946709, so differentiating between the two as a value isn't useful. The problem is that .Net formats 6.89999999999999946709 as "6.90...".

Comment: After some sleep I understand now that this are just two representations of the same number (with a different number of decimal digits) and that your question really is only about formatting. I searched MSDN a while, but could not find a way to suppress rounding when formatting, which seemed to me to be what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Another method, starting with the method:

```
double i = (10 * 0.69);
Console.Write(ToStringFull(i));       // Output 6.89999999999999946709294817
Console.Write(ToStringFull(-6.9)      // Output -6.90000000000000035527136788
Console.Write(ToStringFull(i - 6.9)); // Output -0.00000000000000088817841970012523233890533
```

### A Drop-In Function...

```
public static string ToStringFull(double value)
{
    if (value == 0.0) return "0.0";
    if (double.IsNaN(value)) return "NaN";
    if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(value)) return "-Inf";
    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(value)) return "+Inf";

    long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
    BigInteger mantissa = (bits & 0xfffffffffffffL) | 0x10000000000000L;
    int exp = (int)((bits >> 52) & 0x7ffL) - 1023;
    string sign = (value < 0) ? "-" : "";

    if (54 > exp)
    {
        double offset = (exp / 3.321928094887362358); //...or =Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value))
        BigInteger temp = mantissa * BigInteger.Pow(10, 26 - (int)offset) >> (52 - exp);
        string numberText = temp.ToString();
        int digitsNeeded = (int)((numberText[0] - '5') / 10.0 - offset);
        if (exp < 0)
            return sign + "0." + new string('0', digitsNeeded) + numberText;
        else
            return sign + numberText.Insert(1 - digitsNeeded, ".");
    }
    return sign + (mantissa >> (52 - exp)).ToString();
}
```

### How it works

To solve this problem I used the BigInteger tools. Large values are simple as they just require left shifting the mantissa by the exponent. For small values we cannot just directly right shift as that would lose the precision bits.  We must first give it some extra size by multiplying it by a 10^n and then do the right shifts. After that, we move over the decimal n places to the left. More text/code [here](https://github.com/SunsetQuest/Extended-Precision-Formatting-of-Doubles/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, double printing is broken in .NET, they are printing trailing garbage digits.

You can read how to implement it correctly [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf).

I have had to do the same for IronScheme.

```
> (* 10.0 0.69)
6.8999999999999995
> 6.89999999999999946709
6.8999999999999995
> (- 6.9 (* 10.0 0.69))
8.881784197001252e-16
> 6.9
6.9
> (- 6.9 8.881784197001252e-16)
6.8999999999999995
```

Note: Both C and C# has correct value, just broken printing.

Update: I am still looking for the mailing list conversation I had that lead up to this discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I found this quick fix.

```
    double i = 10 * 0.69;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);


    String s = String.Format("{0:F20}", i).Substring(0,20);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s + " " +s.Length );
```