# Issue with calculation in function

Tags: pascal, calc

I'm quite new to programming and I can't get a function to calculate properly. It is a compound interest calculator that uses this formula:

I = P ( 1 + i )n — P (p= principal i= interest n= years) Rate := to interest value.

On pascal  my function looks like this,

```
function Compoundinterest(principal, years: integer; rate: double): double;

var
divrate: double;
interest: Double;


begin

divrate := rate/100;
interest := principal * power(1 + divrate, years) - Principal;
result := interest; 

end;
```

It compiles fine but just wont return the right value.

for example 1000 principal, 15% interest over 3 years returns this : 1.52087500000000E+000.

I assume I'm doing something wrong in the formula?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In pascal, a function returns what it's name has been set to within the function. For example:

```
function set_one(): integer;

begin
   set_one := 1
end;
```

In your function, you should replace

```
result := interest;
```

with

```
Compoundinterest := interest;
```

or to show in completion (with a few changes):

```
function compound_interest(principal, years: integer; rate: double): double;
var
   divrate: double;

begin
   divrate := rate / 100.0;
   compound_interest := principal * power(1 + divrate, years) - principal;
end;
```

However, this assumes that you have access to the `power` function. In order to access the `power` function, the program must have: `uses math` written under the program header. This code was tested on compiles on Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4.

For more info on Pascal, see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_functions.htm

For an online Pascal terminal, see:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_pascal_online.php

Answer (score 0):

I tested here with Free Pascal 3.0.0 and it works (5.20875. I added

```
 {$mode delphi}
 uses math;
```

before your code and

```
begin
 writeln(compoundinterest(1000,3,15));
end.
```

after. Verify that you do this too, or explain more about which pascal system you use.

If this is only a first step in some calculation you might also be interested in the [math unit financial functions](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/cashflowfunctions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the format of decimal using 
`:0:2`

> Try this

`result := interest:0:2;`

[Counting the number of decimal places in pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550401/counting-the-number-of-decimal-places-in-pascal)

```
var
divrate: double;
interest: Double;


begin

divrate := rate/100;
interest := principal * power(1 + divrate, years) - Principal;
result := interest:0:2; 

end;
```

Comment: Thanks heaps that's exactly what I needed :)