# Calculate the unit in the last place (ULP) for doubles

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

Does .NET have a built-in method to calculate the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of a given double or float?

If not, what is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: happy reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668183/find-min-max-of-a-float-double-that-has-the-same-internal-representation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the function is pretty trivial; this is based on the pseudocode in the accepted answer to the question linked by vulkanino:

```
double value = whatever;
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
double nextValue = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits + 1);
double result = nextValue - value;
```

For floats, you'd need to provide your own implementation of `SingleToInt32Bits` and `Int32BitsToSingle`, since BitConverter doesn't have those functions.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) shows the special cases in the java implementation of the function; handling those should be fairly trivial, too.

Comment: When `value` is a `float`, you can use `int bits = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0)` and then `float nextValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(bits + 1), 0)`.

Answer (score 9):

[phoog answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487719/2410359) is good but has weaknesses with negative numbers, max_double, infinity and NaN.

`phoog_ULP(positive x)` --> a positive number.  Good.
`phoog_ULP(negative x)` --> a negative number.  I would expect positive number.
To fix this I recommend instead:

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

Below are fringe cases that need resolution should you care...

`phoog_ULP(x = +/- Max_double 1.797...e+308)` returns an infinite result.  (+1.996...e+292) expected.
`phoog_ULP(x = +/- Infinity)` results in a NaN. +Infinity expected.
`phoog_ULP(x = +/- NaN)` may unexpectedly change from a sNan to a qNaN.  No change expected.   One could argue either way on if the sign should become + in this case.

---

To solve these, I only see a short series of brutish `if()` tests to accommodate these, possible on the "bits" value for expediency.  Example:

```
double ulpc(double value) {
  long long bits = BitConverter::DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
  if ((bits & 0x7FF0000000000000L) == 0x7FF0000000000000L) { // if x is not finite
    if (bits & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFL) { // if x is a NaN
      return value;  // I did not force the sign bit here with NaNs.
      } 
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(0x7FF0000000000000L); // Positive Infinity;
    }
  bits &= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL; // make positive
  if (bits == 0x7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) { // if x == max_double (notice the _E_)
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits) - BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits-1);
  }
  double nextValue = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits + 1);
  double result = nextValue - fabs(value);
  return result;
}
```