# Recover the original number from a float

Tags: java, database, numbers, bigdecimal

Numbers are being stored in a database (out of my control) as floats/doubles etc.

When I pull them out they are *damaged* - for example `0.1` will come out (when formatted) as `0.100000001490116119384765625`.

Is there a reliable way to recover these numbers?

I have tried `new BigDecimal(((Number) o).doubleValue())` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(((Number) o).doubleValue())` but these do not work. I still get the damaged result.

I am aware that I could make assumptions on the number of decimal places and round them but this will break for numbers that are deliberately 0.33333333333 for example.

Is there a simple method that will work for most rationals?

I suppose I am asking *is there a simple way of finding the most minimal rational number that is within a small delta of a float number?*.

Comment: I had asked a similar question yesterday : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22189081/2959259>

Comment: I wouldn't call them "damaged" - it's really just falling victim to how doubles work.  Which is also going to cause problems for stuff like `.3333....`, which can't be represented precisely either (and unless it was stored as the actual fraction, you can't tell if it was `1/3` or actually `.3333`).  What do these values represent?  Perhaps it's unimportant that the exact value is lost?  If you do need the actual precision, why wasn't the db written to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the bludgeon way I have done it - I would welcome a more elegant solution.

I chose an [implementation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/Rational.java.html) of `Rational` that had a `mediant` method ready-made for me.

I refactored it to use `long` instead of `int` and then added:

```
// Default delta to apply.
public static final double DELTA = 0.000001;

public static Rational valueOf(double dbl) {
  return valueOf(dbl, DELTA);
}

// Create a good rational for the value within the delta supplied.
public static Rational valueOf(double dbl, double delta) {
    // Primary checks.
    if ( delta <= 0.0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delta must be > 0.0");
    }
    // Remove the integral part.
    long integral = (long) Math.floor(dbl);
    dbl -= integral;
    // The value we are looking for.
    final Rational d = new Rational((long) ((dbl) / delta), (long) (1 / delta));
    // Min value = d - delta.
    final Rational min = new Rational((long) ((dbl - delta) / delta), (long) (1 / delta));
    // Max value = d + delta.
    final Rational max = new Rational((long) ((dbl + delta) / delta), (long) (1 / delta));
    // Start the fairey sequence.
    Rational l = ZERO;
    Rational h = ONE;
    Rational found = null;
    // Keep slicing until we arrive within the delta range.
    do {
        // Either between min and max -> found it.
        if (found == null && min.compareTo(l) <= 0 && max.compareTo(l) >= 0) {
            found = l;
        }
        if (found == null && min.compareTo(h) <= 0 && max.compareTo(h) >= 0) {
            found = h;
        }
        if (found == null) {
            // Make the mediant.
            Rational m = mediant(l, h);
            // Replace either l or h with mediant.
            if (m.compareTo(d) < 0) {
                l = m;
            } else {
                h = m;
            }
        }

    } while (found == null);

    // Bring back the sign and the integral.
    if (integral != 0) {
        found = found.plus(new Rational(integral, 1));
    }
    // That's me.
    return found;
}    

public BigDecimal toBigDecimal() {
  // Do it to just 4 decimal places.
  return toBigDecimal(4);
}

public BigDecimal toBigDecimal(int digits) {
  // Do it to n decimal places.
  return new BigDecimal(num).divide(new BigDecimal(den), digits, RoundingMode.DOWN).stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

Essentially - the algorithm starts with a range of 0-1. At each iteration I check to see if either end of the range falls between my d-delta - d+delta range. If it does we've found an answer.

If no answer is found we take the [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29) of the two limits and replace one of the limits with it. The limit to replace is chosen to ensure the limits surround `d` at all times.

This is essentially doing a binary-chop search between 0 and 1 to find the first rational that falls within the desired range.

Mathematically I climb down the [Stern-Brocot Tree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stern-BrocotTree.html) choosing the branch that keeps me enclosing the desired number until I fall into the desired delta.

NB: I have not finished my testing but it certainly finds `1/10` for my input of `0.100000001490116119384765625` and `1/3` for `1.0/3.0` and the classic `355/113` for π.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the numbers in the database as String and on the retrieval just parseDouble() them. This way the number wont be damaged, it will be same as you store there.

Comment: I do not have control of the system that creates the records in the database.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simple way of finding a rational number that is within 0.00001 of a float number?.

This is called rounding.

```
double d = ((Number) o).doubleValue();
double d2 = Math.round(d * 1e5) / 1e5;
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d2);
```

or you can use BigDecimal to perform the rounding (I avoid using BigDecimal as it is needelessly slow once you know how to use rounding of doubles)

```
double d = ((Number) o).doubleValue();
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Note: never use `new BigDecimal(double)` unless you understand what it does. Most likely `BigDecial.valueOf(double)` is what you wanted.

Comment: This would not do what I want for 0.333333333333333333333. In that case I still want 0.333333333333333333333. `BigDecial.valueOf(double)` did not help.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon if you have lost information using a `double` (or any other type) then using `BigDecimal` will not resurrect it.