# smallest float that can be summed to another float

Tags: c#, floating-point, epsilon

Assuming there's a float number with 7 digits how to find the smallest number that can be added to that float?

Example 1: 1234.567f + 0000.001f = 1234.568f

Example 2: 0.01234567 + 0.00000001f = 0.01234568f

Comment: In C (or C++), you'd call `nextafter` and subtract.  Unfortunately there is no .NET wrapper for this useful operation.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485943/calculate-the-unit-in-the-last-place-ulp-for-doubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP added `C#` after posting of this `C` answer.

Will leave this C solution up as a reference.

---

Print the number out in exponential format and change each digit, to '0' or '1'

```
float smallest_float_summable(float f, int digs) {
  char buf[20];

  sprintf(buf, "%.*e", digs - 1, f);
  char *p = buf;
  while (*p != 'e') {
    if (isdigit(*p)) {
      *p = '0' + (p[1] == 'e');
    }
    p++;
  }
  float y;
  sscanf(buf, "%e", &y);
  return y;
}

 printf("%e\n", smallest_float_summable(1234.567f, 7));
 // 1.000000e-03
```

This will not get  the *smallest* as the typically a number near 1/2 the value of `smallest_float_summable()` will effect the change, yet this seems to match OP's intent.

---

To get the smallest number that will effect some change, simple use `nextafter()`

> The `nextafter` functions determine the next representable value, in the type of the function, after `x` in the direction of `y` ...  C11dr §7.12.11.3 2

```
#include <math.h>
float smallest_change(float f) {
  float dif = f - nextafterf(f, 0);
  return dif;
}
```

[Edit]

[@aka.nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282453/smallest-float-that-can-be-summed-to-another-float/33282659?noredirect=1#comment54372333_33282659) correctly points out that even smaller, maybe about `1/2 dif` will effect a change.  Will ponder this.

Comment: But assuming IEEE 754 default rounding mode, you could have an even smaller dif number if f significand is odd no? dif would then be 1/2 ulp

Comment: @aka.nice Good point.  Will need some thought to cover corner cases as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To find the smallest epsilon, you could start with 10eN where N is 1, and move down to a smaller number and add it.  Then compare it to the original number.

```
number = x

N = 1
newnumber = 3
while (number <> newnumber){
  newnumber = (number + 10eN)
  N = N - 1
}

Then 10e(N+1) is the smallest epsilon.
```

Comment: If `number` was large like `1e30`, then `N` would need to start with a greater value like 24 or more rather than 1.