# C# equivalent to eps(X) function in matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am trying to translate some matlab code to C# and have hit a problem. Its a numerical algorithm and matlab sets a tolerance which is based on the `eps()` function.

The matlab documentation (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) says:

**d = eps(X) is the positive distance from abs(X) to the next larger in magnitude floating point number of the same precision as X. X may be either double precision or single precision**

As far as I can tell, there is no native C# function which does the same thing. I am a physicist by trade so the intricacies of floating point operations are not something I really know about. Can someone point me in the right direction?

tl;dr: How to calculate the equivalent of eps(x) in C#?

Comment: It's called an [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) and the question has been answered before for C# [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485943/calculate-the-unit-in-the-last-place-ulp-for-doubles) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668183/find-min-max-of-a-float-double-that-has-the-same-internal-representation).

Comment: aha! If I'd known it was called ULP I may have found those...thanks!

Comment: I am surprised that nobody mentioned Epsilon. In C# _float.Epsilon_ is 1.401298E-45; _double.Epsilon_ is 4.94065645841247E-324 (on my machine)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can compute `eps` yourself in matlab as follows:

```
x=1; p=0; y=1; z=x+y;
while x~=z
   y=y/2; p=p+1; z=x+y; 
end
eps_ = y*2
eps
```

output:

```
eps_ =

  2.2204e-016


ans =

  2.2204e-016
```

The code is from: *Introduction to Scientific Computing*, C. F. van Loan

Comment: While this is a good exercise for anyone learning about floating-point, note that this is not how `eps` or ULP in other languages is actually calculated under the hood or should be calculated in real code: [see here for efficient C code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#How_to_determine_machine_epsilon).