# Why Is ToString() Rounding My Double Value?

Tags: .net, rounding, tostring

How do I prevent my double value from being rounded when converting to a string?  I have tried both `Convert.ToString` and `ToString()` with the same result.

For example my double may look something like `77.987654321`, and the two strings conversions convert to to `77.98765`.  I need to keep the precision of the value as is.

Comment: For me ToString() keeps the precision. Some code would be nice.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default the `.ToString()` method of `Double` returns 15 digits of precision. If you want the full 17 digits that the double value holds internally, you need to pass the "G17" format specifier to the method.

```
String s = value.ToString("G17");
```

Sourced from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx):

> By default, the return value only
>   contains 15 digits of precision
>   although a maximum of 17 digits is
>   maintained internally. If the value of
>   this instance has greater than 15
>   digits, ToString returns
>   PositiveInfinitySymbol or
>   NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the
>   expected number. If you require more
>   precision, specify format with the
>   "G17" format specification, which
>   always returns 17 digits of precision,
>   or "R", which returns 15 digits if the
>   number can be represented with that
>   precision or 17 digits if the number
>   can only be represented with maximum
>   precision.

Comment: It makes one wonder why they don't just return all 17 digits automatically, and let users round it if they want to.

Comment: @Robert: I know what you mean. It's strange that they miss them off. If it was hundreds I'd understand, but for the sake of 2 digits it seems odd.

Comment: Note that it says "a *maximum* of 17 digits". The last two may probably be inaccurate, which seems like a valid reason to leave them out by default.

Comment: @Robert: Because you hardly ever need them. 15 digits is enough to almost always recover the right number, and it also means that rounding often works to shorten the number correctly. Doing better than that is possible, but the code to do it is *much* more complex and few languages/libraries bother. (Tcl is one that does which is why I know a bit more about this than most folks...)

Answer (score 16):

Try something like

```
myDouble.ToString("R")
```

See also [The Round-trip ("R") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString):

> The round-trip ("R") format specifier guarantees that a numeric value that is converted to a string will be parsed back into the same numeric value.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet's `DoubleConverter` class has a `ToExactString()` method which will return the exact value of the double as a string.

https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Comment: You should probably ask Jon, but it's most likely "use it however you want."  Most of Jon's GitHub projects are either Apache or BSD.

Comment: Updated link: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the main answer for rounding away the last two digits, is to hide numerical instability/rounding due to float/double finite precision.

**Example with no rounding:**

```
(Math.Sqrt(7)).ToString("G17") = "2.6457513110645907"

(Math.Sqrt(7)+6).ToString("G17") = "8.6457513110645898"
```

Looks a bit strange in the last 3 digits, right?

**Example with rounding:**

```
(Math.Sqrt(7)).ToString() = "2.64575131106459"

(Math.Sqrt(7)+6).ToString() = "8.64575131106459"
```

Look "perfect", right?

:-)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using updated versions of .NET/.NET Core:

.NET Core 3.0 introduced a breaking change that changed `double.ToString()` to no longer use `"G15"` as the default format. Instead `ToString()` returns the shortest string that when parsed returns the same value.

Therefore, to maintain precision, you can simply use `ToString()`.

This is similar to older versions' `"R"` format specifier, but even that was apparently not 100% accurate prior to this change.

See [Breaking changes in .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0#floating-point-formatting-and-parsing-behavior-changed)

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but try ToString("R").