# Problems Adding two double numbers

Tags: c#, console

I have very stupid issue i am simply taking input of on double and adding it to other double which is already declared and assign a value but sum is not showing floating point

```
double d = 4.0;
// Getting second double from user
double numDouble = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//Printing double number :
Console.WriteLine(d + numDouble);
```

result is always `4.0 + 2.0 = 6` but i want **6.0**
any idea

Comment: Take a look at MSDN for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Math says, that

```
 6 = 6.0 = 6.00 = 6.000 = ...
```

so what you want is a *representation* of `double` value as a `string`:

```
 // F1: - one digit after decimal point
 Console.WriteLine((d + numDouble).ToString("F1"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked in my case so i was missing to convert it to string and formatting that string

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F1}", d + numDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to format your string for the output.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0}", (d + numDouble)));
```

<sub>[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570823/8303093)</sub>