# Why is c#'s precision for float.MaxValue more than it lets on?

Tags: c#, numbers, double, precision

C# code:

```
double value = float.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(value / 2);
```

give different values (C# gives 1.70141173319264E+38 and C# without floats gives me 1.701411735e+38) me .

When I use the c# code:

```
double value = 3.40282347E+38;
Console.WriteLine(value / 2);
```

I get the same as floats. Is MSDN wrong?

[Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vUgl62)
float.MaxValue is 3.40282347E+38.
[Float MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.single.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *JavaSccript/C# without floats gives me* ... what?

Comment: IMO just remove `javascript` entirely and ask why `double value = float.MaxValue / 2` is different than `double value = 3.40282347E+38 / 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddling around I found that
`Console.WriteLine(((3.40282347E+38 / 2) == (float.MaxValue / 2)).ToString());` prints `False` while `Console.WriteLine(((3.40282347E+38f / 2) == (float.MaxValue / 2)).ToString());` prints `True`. It's because the language does this:

[By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment operator is treated as double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx).

Your  number is a `double` and you are comparing it against a `float`, so the precision is different by default. You have to force the number to be a `float` by adding `f` on the end of it.

Comment: `float.MaxValue - 3.40282347E+38F` = 0

Comment: Is the extra precision on the double, false precision (or does float.MaxValue have more precision than floats?

Comment: `float` is an alias for `Single`. `double` is `Double`'s alias. It's quite literally about twice as much precision.

Comment: How can float.MaxValue's precision be more than a floats, then a float can't store it?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 It's not. You are implicitly casting the `float` to a `double`: `double value = float.MaxValue`, which is adding a bunch of digits (the specifics of which I would have to research, e.g., read the discussion under the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp)). `float value = float.MaxValue` is a different precision and ends up being a different number than `double value = float.MaxValue`

Comment: @trinalbadger587 And to be clear, yes, I *think* the "extra precision on the double is false precision". Casting `float.MaxValue` from its float precision to a double will add digits, but you didn't not gain any precision from the original `float` number. The extra digits are not necessarily incorrect as long as they fall inside of the "interval" of double precision datatype. Again, this level of detail is beyond my on-the-spot understanding of the datatypes, which is why I suggested reading the other thread (or better yet get a book on the subject).