# Double-formatting on time

Tags: c#, format, double

How can I set `TotalHours` to be in double format, or what I need to do to get the result in `txtBoxMonatstotal` as a result of `93.3`.
This is my code:

```
private void calendar1_MonthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(calendar1.CurrentDate.Year, calendar1.CurrentDate.Month, 1);
    DateTime stop = new DateTime(calendar1.CurrentDate.Year, calendar1.CurrentDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    int numberOfWorkDays = GetNumberOfWorkingDays(start, stop);

    double shouldWorkPerMonth = tag_durschnit * numberOfWorkDays;
    double workedPerMonth = workingHours.Where(x => x.Key.Date.Year == start.Year && x.Key.Month == start.Month).Sum(x => x.Value.TotalHours);
    double saldo = workedPerMonth - shouldWorkPerMonth;

    txtBoxMonatstotal.Text = workedPerMonth.ToString();
    txtBoxSollzeit.Text = shouldWorkPerMonth.ToString();
    txtBoxSaldo.Text = saldo.ToString();

}
```

The current result looks like this:
 
[image: txtBoxMonatstotal]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Round the value first before converting it to string. [Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is what you should do: `Math.Round(workedPerMonth).ToString("N1")`.

Comment: Or you could just format your output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp

Comment: try handling the format : `workedPerMonth.ToString("00.0")`

Comment: thanks a lot @MongZhu that's right workedPerMonth.ToString("00.0")

Comment: do you care about the decimal on the second place? if the value would be `93.39` would you want to print `93.4` ?

Comment: 93.4 its ok.. thank you

Comment: then you need to round first! `workedPerMonth.ToString("00.0")` will give you `93.3` if the value is `93.39`. It will only cut away all decimals after the first decimal place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx) the number first and then call `ToString` on it

```
txtBoxMonatstotal.Text = System.Math.Round(workedPerMonth, 1).ToString();
```

the second parameter in `Round` determines

> the number of fractional digits in the return value.