# How to display a double number as same as input (non floating-point and non hex char)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a website about Farm management. 
There are Detail and Edit Farm pages that user can edit the size(m2) of each Farm. 
Size is stored in DB as Float number.

There are some cases that user input a size as non floating-point number like: 1111111111111111 (length >= 16) then size will be stored in DB like 1.11111111111111E+15.

I am now looking for the way to show Size in Detail page as same as what user has inputed (without hexadecimal char and floating-point).

```
<td style="white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word">@size.ToString()</td>
```

**Now:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Type of Size is `double`

Thanks!

Comment: typeof(size) in c# ?

Comment: it is double @Mate

Comment: Check https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs from https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint ... another solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation

Comment: use `decimal` and convert your string into number `@decimal.Parse("1.11111111111111E+15", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any).ToString()`

Comment: it converts into a wrong number: 1111111111111110. It should be 1111111111111111 @LaljiDhameliya

Comment: you sure your exponentiation number is `1.11111111111111E+15` because you check it online it convert to `1111111111111110` this number  https://www.free-online-calculator-use.com/scientific-notation-converter.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp