# How *exactly* does C# convert double to decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal, precision

The following C# code prints 0.1 - why?

```
var s = "0.1";
var dbl = Double.Parse(s);
var dcml = Convert.ToDecimal(dbl);
Console.WriteLine(dcml.ToString());
```

Isn't 0.01 not representable in binary, therefore it should print 0.100000001490116 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp

Comment: Note that 0.100000001490116 is the result of calling `Single.Parse`, not `Double.Parse`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `dbl` is precisely 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

That's 0.1 to 17 significant digits.

The [documentation for `Convert.ToDecimal(Double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_Double_) states:

> The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.

The [conversion from `Single` (aka `float`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_Single_) is documented to truncate earlier:

> The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of seven significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than seven significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.

If you call `Convert.ToDecimal(Double)` with a value initially converted from 0.1f, it will display 0.100000001490116:

```
double dbl = 0.1f;        
decimal dcml = (decimal) dbl;
Console.WriteLine(dcml);
```

Comment: alright, this does answer my question, but I'd still like to know what's going on with Single in the same case, as the Single's behavior casts doubt on our understanding of the Decimal's behavior.

Comment: @zvolkov: I'm looking into it.

Comment: @zvolkov: Doh - I shouldn't have used `var`. That was the problem. If you convert it with `double x = 0.1f;` then it's fine.

Comment: @zvolkov: Answer edited, and I think it explains everything.