# double.ToString(string) with custom numeric format string does not produce the expected result

Tags: c#, double

I want to display double values with a specific number of decimal digits.

The documentation for custom numeric formats for double.ToString(string) says:

*The "0" custom format specifier serves as a zero-placeholder symbol. If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string. The position of the leftmost zero before the decimal point and the rightmost zero after the decimal point determines the range of digits that are always present in the result string.*

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#Specifier0

All examples given in the documentation for double.ToString(string) result in what I would expect from the above quote.

However, this does not seem to work in all cases for me:

```
double d = 63712373026.615219;
d.ToString("R"); // "63712373026.615219"
d.ToString("G17"); // "63712373026.615219"
d.ToString("0.000000") // "63712373026.615200"
d.ToString("#.######") // "63712373026.6152"
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Note that you've got 18 digits of precision there, which is about at the limits of double precision. Expect rounding weirdness.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought at first, but the roundtrip fromat specifiers prove that this value can be printed completely, thus I would expect the custom format specifiers to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point numbers are approximations: they have a limited number of bits, and they do their best to represent a number close to the one you asked for within the constraints of the available bits.

Most of the time this works fine, but things start breaking down as you reach the limits of their precision which is around 16 digits for `double` and 9 digits for `float`.

Specifically, a double cannot represent `63712373026.615219` exactly. With `G50` or [Jon Skeet's `DoubleConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp/1658420), we can take a look at the exact number that the double does represent:

```
63712373026.615219.ToString("G50"); // 63712373026.6152191162109375
```

We're fine up to the 7th decimal place, but see how the closest representable number to `63712373026.615219` is actually a little bit larger?

With some trial-and-error, we can see the range of values which all get represented as `63712373026.6152191162109375`:

```
63712373026.6152230.ToString("G50"); // 63712373026.61522674560546875
63712373026.6152229.ToString("G50"); // 63712373026.6152191162109375
63712373026.615219.ToString("G50");  // 63712373026.6152191162109375
63712373026.6152154.ToString("G50"); // 63712373026.6152191162109375
63712373026.6152153.ToString("G50"); // 63712373026.61521148681640625
```

The precision limitations of `double` mean that everything between `63712373026.6152154` and `63712373026.6152229` gets stored as the number `63712373026.6152191162109375`.

This presents a problem for the formatter: if you asked for `63712373026.615219.ToString("0.000000")`, should it give you `63712373026.615223` or `63712373026.615215` or anything in between?

In practice, what it appears to do is to work out the range of possible values which the double might be representing, and then round to the digits which are common to all. Since `63712373026.6152229` and `63712373026.6152154` and everything in between all start with `63712373026.6152`, that is what the formatter works with. Which is why it will print `63712373026.615200` if you force it to: it knows that it doesn't have enough information to fill in those last 2 digits.

---

Note that I think the round-trip and `G17` formats are misleading you slightly. Round-trip basically prints the *fewest* digits which will be parsed back into the same underlying double value. So `63712373026.615219` contains the smallest number of decimal places which gets parsed back into `63712373026.6152191162109375`.

Note that they fixed `R` on .NET 5:

```
63712373026.615219.ToString("R"); // 63712373026.61522
```

`G17` just prints 17 digits, regardless of the underlying value of the double. Because double only has around 16 digits of precision, this is also enough to safely *round-trip* the double.

This can be seen with simpler values, such as `0.1`. `double`, not being base 10, can't exactly represent `0.1`. Instead its closest value is:

```
0.1.ToString("G99"); // 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

However:

```
0.1.ToString("R"); // 0.1
```

The *shortest* value which gets represented as `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` is `0.1`, so this is what `R` returns, even though it doesn't *quite* match the underlying representation. This is fine, because parsing `0.1` will result in a double whose underlying representation is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, thus successfully round-tripping it.

Comment: This is a great and comprehensive answer, but I still think that according to the documentation, and according to what I would expect, it should be 63712373026.615219, not because that is the number I entered, but because it is the appropriately truncated version of 63712373026.6152191162109375.

Accordingly, 63712373026.615223.ToString("0.000000") should also be 63712373026.615219.

So I would say that your answer is correct, but the documentation by Microsoft is clearly wrong. Your guess of what this format specifier does seems to be more correct than the documentation.

Comment: I suspect they kept that as an implementation detail, and the docs only cover the cases where the double has sufficient precision to represent the values in question. I believe the runtime uses the Grisu3 / Dragon4 algorithms: maybe they provide further detail?

Comment: My *guess* is that `"0"` is defined to operate on the Dragon4 decimal representation of the floating-point number, and not its raw underlying value. That would make sense, but I don't have much more than a hunch to back it up