# Simple floating point arithmetic in VBA throwing error

Tags: excel, vba, function, floating-point

I have the following code in an Excel VBA module:

```
Function f(a, b, c, d)
f = 1.95 * a * (b / c) ^ 0.06 * (d / c) ^ 0.06
End Function

Sub callf()
Debug.Print (f(-7, 10, 3.5, -6))
End Sub
```

When I run the sub `callf` I get an error:

> Run time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

I am at a loss as to why this occurs. Am I not doing simple floating point operations here? Any ideas?

Comment: Because you are [raising `-1.7` to the power `0.06`](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2174393). The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-6+%2F+3.5%29+%5E+0.06) is a complex number.

Comment: Right.... raising a negative number to a fractional power results in a complex number *face palm*

Comment: In your case it does, though not always, of course. -8^(1/3), for example, is real.

Comment: @JosWoolley yes, or the cubic root of -64. But trying in powershell actually still gives NaN which is strange `[Math]::Pow(-8,1/3)`

Comment: @user32882 Because the result of calculating `1/3` is [not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683) one third.

Comment: @GSerg In that case why does PowerShell not have an issue with `[Math]::Pow(8,1/3)`, correctly returning 2?

Comment: @JosWoolley Because the result of `Pow(8, 0.333333333333333)` is `1.9999999999999986...`, which is rounded to `2` according to [this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658420/11683).

Comment: @GSerg you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are [raising `-1.7` to the power `0.06`](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2174393). The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-6+%2F+3.5%29+%5E+0.06) is a complex number.