# Complex number displaying as incredibly small decimal

Tags: c#, .net, math, floating-point, mathnet-numerics

Was using a method from the MathNet Library and tried applying its Cubic root finding function, but it outputs incredibly long decimals, and rounding doesn't seem to affect them.

```cs
public static (Complex, Complex, Complex) FindCubic(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    double num = b * b - 3.0 * a * c;
    double num2 = 2.0 * b * b * b - 9.0 * a * b * c + 27.0 * a * a * d;
    double num3 = -1.0 / (3.0 * a);
    if ((num2 * num2 - 4.0 * num * num * num) / (-27.0 * a * a) == 0.0)
    {
        if (num == 0.0)
        {
            Complex complex = new Complex(num3 * b, 0.0);
            return (complex, complex, complex);
        }
        Complex complex2 = new Complex((9.0 * a * d - b * c) / (2.0 * num), 0.0);
        Complex item = new Complex((4.0 * a * b * c - 9.0 * a * a * d - b * b * b) / (a * num), 0.0);
        return (complex2, complex2, item);
    }
    (Complex, Complex, Complex) tuple = ((num == 0.0) ? new Complex(num2, 0.0).CubicRoots() : ((num2 + Complex.Sqrt(num2 * num2 - 4.0 * num * num * num)) / 2.0).CubicRoots());
    return (num3 * (b + tuple.Item1 + num / tuple.Item1), num3 * (b + tuple.Item2 + num / tuple.Item2), num3 * (b + tuple.Item3 + num / tuple.Item3));
}
```

The code above works fine, but really not sure how to shorten the decimals in the results. For example if the output should be (-1, 0) in theory (and it does display so on most calculators), it instead displays (-1, -2.0354088784794536E-16), which is close to  0, and *should be* displayed as 0.

```cs
Round(num3, 0) * (b + new Complex (Round(tuple.Item1.Real, 0), Round(tuple.Item1.Imaginary, 0)) + num / tuple.Item1)
```

The rounding code in question since you can't directly round complex numbers.

Solved in comment: Forgot about floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: @YakovGalka rounding to 0 using Math.Round gives yet another mess of decimals. It does round, just not to 0. The care part is mostly because it should be exactly 0 really.

Comment: @YakovGalka Actually that's my bad then, forgot about the whole floating point thing, thanks.

Comment: "For example if the output should be (-1, 0)" --> what are the values of `a, b, c, d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with the answer you get. Remember that [floating point calculations are inherently approximate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/277176). Indeed, the distance between `(1,0)` and `(1, -2.0354088784794536E-16)` is less than 1ulp. What most calculators do to avoid such unpleasant outputs is to calculate with a couple extra digits and round the result to fit the display.

As for your rounding code, it rounds intermediary results rather than the final answer:

```
Round(num3, 0) * (b + new Complex (Round(tuple.Item1.Real, 0), Round(tuple.Item1.Imaginary, 0)) + num / tuple.Item1)
```

What you want instead is something like this:

```
int digits = 8;
Complex tmp = num3 * (b + tuple.Item1 + num / tuple.Item1);
tmp = new Complex(Round(tmp.Real, digits), Round(tmp.Imaginary, digits));
```

Though the best practice would be to let the [rounding happen in the formatting routine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421520/277176).

Comment: "distance between (1,0) and (1, -2.0354088784794536E-16) is less than 1ulp" may be less than 1 ULP of 1.0, but it is not less than 1.0 ULP in general.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The term "ULP" is always relative to some specific value, so I'm not sure what you mean by "1.0 ULP in general". I acknowledge that using ULP on complex numbers does not have a commonly agreed definition. My intent here is that you'd use ULP relative to the modulus |z| of the complex number, which is a natural extension from reals. A better way to phrase it might be that |a-b|/|a| < ε