# How to use double datatype while multiplying with the Integer value?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I am having the function to truncate the decimal places of the double datatype vaiable which is given below

```
             public double GetTruncate(double tobeTruncated, int divideFactor)
      {            
        if (divideFactor == 0)
            return Math.Truncate((double)tobeTruncated);
        else
        {
            tobeTruncated = tobeTruncated * divideFactor;
            tobeTruncated = Math.Truncate((double)tobeTruncated);
            tobeTruncated = tobeTruncated / divideFactor;
        }
        return tobeTruncated;


    }
```

**Example : tobeTruncated = 35.66 dividefactor = 100**

While executing the above line , i am getting the value for tobeTruncated as **3565.9999999999995**,instead of **3566**. I dont know the reason.

**When i changed the double variable to decimal , i am getting the correct answer**. The modified function with correct answer is given below :

```
           public double GetTruncate(double tobeTruncated, int divideFactor)
    {           

        decimal nTempData = (decimal)tobeTruncated;
        if (divideFactor == 0)
            return (double)Math.Truncate((decimal)nTempData);
        else
        {
            nTempData = nTempData * divideFactor;
            nTempData = Math.Truncate((decimal)nTempData);
            nTempData = nTempData / (decimal)divideFactor;
        }
        return (double)nTempData;

    }
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) datatype represents fixed precision numbers.  The [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) datatype represents floating-point numbers, which are an approximation and s[hould not be used when absolute precision is required](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers can only be approximated with the finite amount of bits your computer uses to store them. The result is what you're seeing.

Read: [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net)

Read: [Binary floating point and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)

And read: [Why Do Computers Suck at Math?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-do-computers-suck-at-math.html)