# printf changing the value while using %.22f

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I have a issue with basic typecasting.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf("%.22f",0.30);
     return 1;
}
```

The output I am getting is 0.2999999999999999888978

Why is 0.3 converted to a lesser value

Any help much appreciated

Nandish

Comment: No, you have an issue with your inability to search before asking a question that's been asked a gazillion times before. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#searching

Comment: Thank you Mr  Paxdiablo. But you don't need to  be so harsh putting across your thoughts about my search abilities

Comment: I know [this question says .NET in the can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net), but it's really the same thing.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be harsh, I was helping out by pointing you to the relevant section of the FAQ, detailing _exactly_ how searching works. Being harsh would have been pointing out that, as someone who has been a member here for seven months, you should have figured it out by now :-) Try to take it as helpful advice rather than criticism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `0.30` cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point.
Internally, only an approximation to `0.30` can be stored. Therefore, when you print it all out, you'll get a slightly different number.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: @NandishA: please consider accepting the most appropriate answer of your question, if the issue is resolved or question answered, to keep up the enthusiasm of users.