# Math.Floor Behaviour

Tags: c#, .net

```
double c, d, e;
double a = (c - d) / e;
double b = Math.Floor(a);
Debug.WriteLine(a.ToString() + " " + b.ToString());
```

Code above outputs "3 2" at one configuration where all numbers are double. How is this possible? Is it because of fractional error resulting from double operations? However I think `a.ToString()` should give the whole number with its fractional part.

Comment: This is an incomplete code snippet.  You haven't shown either the definitions of, or the values of, `c`, `d`, or `e`.

Comment: I guess `a` is something like `2.99999999999968768`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net

Comment: Obligaory Reference: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or Why don’t my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de)

Comment: As I said everything is double

Comment: @AlpHancioglu And as I've said, you should show the definitions of **and the values of** `c`, `d`, and `e`.

Comment: @JanDvorak If it is 2.99999999999968768 then why I can't see it as a.ToString() shows the fractional part?

Comment: @AlpHancioglu because `toString` does some rounding, apparently. See JonSkeet's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a matter of what [`double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad.aspx) does. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating the same thing:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find the largest double less than 3
        long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(3);
        double a = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits - 1);
        double b = Math.Floor(a);
        // Print them using the default conversion to string...
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + " " + b.ToString());
        // Now use round-trip formatting...
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("r") + " " + b.ToString("r"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 2
2.9999999999999996 2
```

Now `double.ToString()` is documented with:

> This version of the ToString method implicitly uses the general numeric format specifier ("G") and the NumberFormatInfo for the current culture.

... and the [general numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) docs state:

> The precision specifier defines the maximum number of significant digits that can appear in the result string. If the precision specifier is omitted or zero, the type of the number determines the default precision, as indicated in the following table.

... where the table shows that the default precision for `double` is 15. If you consider 2.9999999999999996 rounded to 15 significant digits, you end up with 3.

In fact, the *exact* value of `a` here is:

```
2.999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

... which again, is 3 when regarded with 15 significant digits.